# How to find a sum of list items with one of two possibilities using Python

Tags: python

If I have a solution which is 4.5, for example, and have two lists of 10 real numbers each, where in each position (1st n, 2nd n, 3rd n..) only one of the entries from both lists can be used per entry, and I need to find all combinations following this rule that will equal the solution number, how can this be accomplished?

eg: solution number = 4.5

1st number can be either 0.75 or 0.1,
2nd number can be either 0.35 or 0.05,
3rd number can be either
....
10th number can be either 0.05 or 0.03.

How can I find all of the potential combinations where each position is included once, being either of the two options per position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of elements is relatively low, you could use `itertools.product` to generate every possible selection and look at the sums.  For example, if we start with

```
lists = [[0.75, 0.35, 0.05], [0.1, 0.05, 0.03]]
target = 0.83
tol = 0.001
```

then

```
from itertools import product
choices = zip(*lists)
solutions = [p for p in product(*choices) if abs(sum(p)-target) < tol]
```

gives

```
>>> solutions
[(0.75, 0.05, 0.03)]
```

---

This works because `zip(*lists)` gives us tuples describing each choice we can only make one of:

```
>>> list(zip(*lists))
[(0.75, 0.1), (0.35, 0.05), (0.05, 0.03)]
```

and then `product` gives us every possible group of choices:

```
>>> list(product(*zip(*lists)))
[(0.75, 0.35, 0.05), (0.75, 0.35, 0.03), (0.75, 0.05, 0.05), (0.75, 0.05, 0.03), (0.1, 0.35, 0.05), (0.1, 0.35, 0.03),]
```

Note that this kind of brute-force search will become infeasible very quickly as the lists grow in size, but if they're short it's not too bad.  If you only care about finding *any* solution, you could do

```
>>> next(p for p in product(*choices) if abs(sum(p)-target) < tol)
(0.75, 0.05, 0.03)
```

which would stop as soon as one is found.